# Zero-mean unit variance complex value independent Gaussian Random Variables in Matrix

Tags: random-matrices, eigenvalues

Let $G$ be $m\times n (m\ge n)$ random matrix of zero-mean unit variance complex value independent Gaussian Random Variables. Then what is distribution of eigenvalues of $G^HG$ and how to obtain the second moment? I tried to do some multiplication of $G^HG$ for small $m, n$, but I still don't know how to solve this.

Comment: posted also at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2682520/zero-mean-unit-variance-complex-value-independent-gaussian-random-variables-in-m

Comment: Open Mehta's book on RMT, or google "Wishart matrix"